# Как проверить, работает ли history api в pjax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-history-api, pjax

Всем привет. Решил использовать [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) на своем сайте. Это библиотека jQuery, которая помогает не грузить страницу полностью, а лишь её часть при переходе по ссылкам.

В интернете мало понятной информации для работы с ним. Всё сделал по англоязычной инструкции, но не понятно, работает или нет.

Смотрел так: если header не исчезает при переходе на другую страницу, то как бы работает. Так было, но иногда и исчезал блок header при переходе, и видно было, что грузится страница полностью.

Что я пробовал:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pjax.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
      // pjax
      $('a').pjax('#wrap')
    })
</script>    
</head>
<body>

<div id="header"> <a href='/'>Главная</a> <a href='/page'>Страница</a> </div>

<div id="wrap">
    code...
    <div id="content"> code... </div>
    code...
</div>

</body>
```

Вопрос, собственно, в чём: как проверять, работает или нет? И как лучше всего в моём случае реализовать?

Comment: Не пользовался, но читал [статью на русском](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/123972/). Может быть вам пригодится.

Comment: Спасибо, дополнительная информация не помешает.

Comment: Девелоперскими инструментами вашего браузера посмотрите, что происходит: подгружается содержание только-#wrap'а, или браузер переходит на новую страницу.

Comment: *Не обратил внимание, что это некро-вопрос из 2012 года.

Answer (score 1):

Поставь в хедере echo date(H:m:s); Как впрочем это и сделано у автора.